# Rails / Sass: Import file from the vendor folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have a stylesheet `app/assets/website/base.scss` that starts with:

```
@import "bootstrap-select.min.css";
```

The `bootstrap-select.min.css` file exists in the `vendor/stylesheets/` folder. When I try to access it in production, I get a 404:

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://mysite.herokuapp.com/assets/bootstrap-select.min.css"

(It works fine on my development rig though.)

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Tried using `@import asset-path("bootstrap-select.min.css")`. Got a syntax error (apparently `asset-path` doesn't work with `import`s).
2. Tried adding `config.assets.precompile += %w(bootstrap-select.min.css)` to `config/environments/production.rb`

Any idea why this might be happening?

*Rails 4.0.4 / Ruby 2.1.2*

Comment: import statement in css file? It's css or .scss?

Comment: @Mandeep it's a .scss (filename is mentioned in the first line)

Comment: On development or production you don't use scss files. Why do you want to compile your scss on production. Also your html should always point to the compiled css file. So where does your final css file reside?

Comment: You are aware that Sass cannot import (compile) CSS files, right?  Does Rails have a feature that allows you to do so?

Comment: @cimmanon oh, I wasn't actually. So that would make sense.. The answer is sprockets then?

Comment: tgpatel: it's called 'website.css' and it resides next to the application.css file. I guess I need to use sprockets to load it up there (I come from a RequireJS background where the optimizer actually replaces @import statements with the actual code so I mistakenly assumed Rails would do the same. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Please add an answer do I can accept

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ended up changing it from `bootstrap-select.min.css` --> `bootstrap-select.min.scss` ..

It worked!

Sass actually places the **contents** of `.scss` files in place - With `.css` files it just links to the file with an `@import`, which is why it wasn't working (thanks @cimmanon!)

Comment: If Sass detects one of these cases: Imports where the URL ends with .css, imports where the URL begins http:// or https://, imports where the URL is written as a url(), imports that have media queries. It will identify the import as a plain CSS command.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you could just remove .css suffix from `@import "bootstrap-select.min.css";` Sass expects from you just the name of the assets and is smart enough to look in all possible asset placements and import whatever it can import (so the name should be format-independent)